# C++ std::find comparing a pointer to a reference

Tags: c++11, lambda, std-function

I am attempting to make a simple Graph system.

(I'm calling my nodes "Cells", but they're just basically nodes)

Here's my header:

```
class Cell {
 public:
  virtual ~Cell() {}
  Cell(int row, int column);
  std::tuple<int, int> getCoord() const;
  void link(Cell& adjacent, bool biDirectional = true);
  void unlink(Cell& adjacent, bool biDirectional = true);
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Cell& cell);
  bool operator==(const Cell& other) const;

 private:
  bool isLinked(const Cell& cell) const;
  int mRow, mColumn;
  std::vector<Cell*> links;
};
```

As you can see, I'm overloading the equivalency operator so I can compare cells by their coordinates. Here's the relevant methods in my `.cpp` file:

```
bool Cell::operator==(const Cell& other) const {
  return mRow == other.mRow && mColumn == other.mColumn;
}

bool Cell::isLinked(const Cell& cell) const {
  return std::end(links) ==
         std::find(std::begin(links), std::end(links),
                   [cell](Cell* cellPtr) { return (*cellPtr) == cell; });
}
```

As you can see, when I want to compare equivalency I check to see if the x,y coordinates are the same. In my `Cell::isLinked` method, I take the `std::vector<Cell*> links`and pass them to `std::find` which then takes the object at the ptr and should then compare it (using the overloaded comparison operator from earlier) and return `true` or `false`.

Instead I'm getting this error when I try to build my project:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:865:22: error: 
      invalid operands to binary expression ('Cell *' and 'const (lambda at Cell.cpp:51:20)')
        if (*__first == __value_)
            ~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
Cell.cpp:50:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::find<std::__1::__wrap_iter<Cell *const *>, (lambda at Cell.cpp:51:20)>' requested here
         std::find(std::begin(links), std::end(links),
```

Comment: Figured it out... `std::find_if` is what you need.

Comment: I was also wrong about my logic. isLinked should check that `std::end(links) !=` instead of is equal